# Generating JSON translation files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intl

my **main problem which I am trying to solve is to generate JSON files from React source code.**

currently I am using for translations react-intl universal package which is working in my App https://github.com/alibaba/react-intl-universal

To solve my main problem I have found this package (I have found only this one, so, if you recommend me something else, i will be glad)

https://github.com/GertjanReynaert/react-intl-translations-manager

As is in guide i have created translationRunner.js (which is in src folder)

```
const manageTranslations = require('react-intl-translations-manager').default;


    manageTranslations({
      messagesDirectory: 'src/translations/extractedMessages',
      translationsDirectory: 'src/translations/locales/',
      languages: ['nl'] // any language you need
    });
```

in my package.json added

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "manage:translations": "node ./translationRunner.js"
```

in render method i have something like

```
<h1>{intl.get('APPBARTITLE')}</h1>
```

if i run translationRunner.js I obtain nl.json which looks like

```
{
}
```

How to obtains json file with my message?

Comment: Do you want the runner to generate `{ "APPBARTITLE": "" }` or what is the exact issue?

Comment: yes, i want to generate { "APPBARTITLE": "" }

Comment: What does `src/translations/extractedMessages` contain?

Comment: subfolder locales and there is nl.json and whitelist_nl.json which has "[
]"

Comment: Does any file in any of those directories contain the localization key you are attempting to translate?

Comment: @ChrisSatchell no

Comment: Check https://github.com/GertjanReynaert/react-intl-translations-manager/issues/64

Comment: where should be babel config located? i have created ".babelrc" file in nodemodules/react-intl with "{
  "presets": ["env", "stage-3"],
  "plugins":  [
    [
      "react-intl",
      {
        "messagesDir": "src/translations/extractedMessages"
      }
    ]
  ]
}" but doesnt help

Comment: Have a look through all of the closed issues, there are a few that had the same issue. Sadly I haven't worked with this library before, so I can't really help you

Comment: [react-intl-universal-extract](https://github.com/alibaba/react-intl-universal/tree/master/packages/react-intl-universal-extract) could extract [react-intl-universal](https://fe-tool.com/react-intl-universal)'s default messages in source code to locale files.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to run

```
npm run build
```

first. The translation manager does not extract the keys you want translated, the babel plugin does.

https://github.com/GertjanReynaert/react-intl-translations-manager/issues/49